# Android send data to xampp server fails when WI-FI is off

Tags: php, android, xampp, google-cloud-messaging

I have an android app that is sending data to GCM and my back end server, which is xampp in my local computer. When WI-FI is on it works like a charm. I get to send data to GCM and my server. But when I use my 3-G data on and turn off the WI-FI it doesn't deliver the data and I get "09-23 13:45:57.165     720-1055/? E/ConnectivityService﹕ net.tcp.usercfg.default not found in system properties. Using defaults 09-23 13:45:57.165     720-1055/? E/ConnectivityService﹕ net.tcp.delack.default not found in system properties." in my stack trace. What is causing this? How do I reslove this?

This the class that sends JSON to the server over 192.168....

```
class SendJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        boolean failure = false;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            try {
                try {
                    URL url;
                    HttpURLConnection urlConn;
                    url = new URL ("http://192.168.*.**/PHPserver/fipage.php");

                    urlConn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                    urlConn.setDoInput (true);
                    urlConn.setDoOutput (true);
                    urlConn.setUseCaches (false);
                    urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
                    urlConn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                    urlConn.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
                    urlConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    urlConn.connect();

                    //Create JSONObject here
                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
                    json.put("stuff", String.valueOf(args[0]));

                    String send=json.toString();

                    // Send POST output.
                    OutputStreamWriter os = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConn.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
                    os.write(send);
                    Log.i("NOTIFICATION", "Data Sent");
                    os.close();

                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream()));
                    String msg="";
                    String line = "";
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        msg += line; }
                    Log.i("msg=",""+msg);
                } catch (MalformedURLException muex) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    muex.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException ioex){
                    ioex.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("ERROR", "There is error sending");

            }
            return null;

        }

    }
```

Comment: do you have network connection without WiFi, if not How are you sending this data?

Comment: @Mark Gilchrist I have a data connection on my phone. Do I have to configure my server to receive data over the internet? How so? I am using my local ip address with WI-FI. Wouldn't that same ip address work?

Comment: I think you will need to post your connection class

Comment: No you cannot use the local ip of your server as the data connection has nothing to do with wifi. Your request reaches your provider but your provider does not know what to do with for instance 192.168.1.2 as there are millions of pc with that local ip.

Comment: when you use the the local network address with wifi it works because the message that leaves your phone is sent to the network router, the router recognizes the ip as a network ip, so it easily finds your host in it, when you use the normal GCM connection, the message is sent from your phone directly to the provider the router is not involved at all, but the provider has no idea what is that ip you want to get to

Comment: Using your public ip is the way to go. Your provider will forward your data to your router. Your public ip is the ip of the router. But your router does not know to which of the many pc's in your home or to which wifi devices the packets have to be delivered. Unless you instruct your router (it has a web interface to do so) to forward the used port to a pc with a specific local ip.

Comment: @greenapps I couldn't get the data delivered to my device. I used port 5228-5230 and TCP/UDP protocols to get GCM messages. But still no luck; stuck on that same error I mentioned above.